# Programmatically add textview and label to nstableView using Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSTableView with multiple rows and just 1 column.
I want to display table in following format:

```
---------------------------- 
| Label - 1                 |
|                           |
| textxtview contents-1     |
| height 20                 |
----------------------------  
| Label - 1                 |
|                           |
| textxtview contents-1     |
| height 40                 |
----------------------------
```

The height of text view should be fixed and its scrollable
Label & text view text color should be different.

How do I programmatically add labels and textview and set the frames?

Comment: Any suggestions about adding contents programatically, i tested sample projects but they dont run, infact end unexpectedly.My all other apps are working fine

Comment: @interface MyViewController : NSViewController <NSCollectionViewDelegate>   shows error in my project as "Cannot find protocol declaration for NSCollectionViewDelegate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe should take a look at NSCollectionView. That's easier to use as you can design the cell view in Interface Builder.

Comment: thanks Christian but i dont know how many elements will be added Its decided at run time, can u suggest me to add it programatically. I am also searching apple docs but cannot get the perfect answer

Comment: NSCollectionView also (like NSTableView) works with a dataSource or a NSArrayController. The content is therefore dynamic. You only design the cell that gets used for each entity.